# Opening a TFS work item in it's own editor

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am trying to create a VS2010 custom start page that will display TFS work items - that part is easy. I am trying to get those work items to open in their normal editor within Visual Studio when they are double-clicked, but I can't see how this can be done.

I've tried using `VsShellUtilities.OpenDocument` with the URI of the work item (it begins vstfs:///) but this cannot be found. I used the http address of the work item - `http://tfs-server:8080/WorkItemTracking/Workitem.aspx?artifactMoniker=id` - but this opened the page in a text editor, and displayed as text. Looking at it in a browser, I'm still not sure that's what I want - but until I can open it in the correct editor, I won't know for sure.

There are many references to `IServiceProvider` and `DocumentService` on the net, and [this page](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsworkitemtracking/thread/16a67089-b117-474d-b32b-c096148cb428/) looks promising, but the objects it references do not appear to exist in TFS2010. Looking on MSDN confirms that they are in 2005, 2008 and 2012 but *not* 2010. The entire `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Controls` namespace doesn't appear to exist in TFS2010, which is a shame because I think that may be what I need.

So am I using the correct path to open a work item in it's own editor, and if I am, how do I go about doing it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a free tfs plugin, tfs extension kit.

It works well and for vs2010 is freeware. Look at [here](http://www.tektfs.com)